# Change of pace – A letter from Gladys

Tags: knowledge, geography, cryptic-crosswords

[image: Empty crossword grid]

Letters from Gladys are geography-themed standalone crosswords. Each puzzle has five thematic answers, which are places, sights or landmarks in or around a certain location (in this case, a city). Each thematic answer is notable enough to have its own article in the English Wikipedia, although not necessarily under the same name that is used here. The goal is to fill the grid, identify the thematic answers and guess the name of Gladys’s destination, which is not indicated in the grid.

> Dear Puzzling,
>
> Today I’m taking a break from all the sun and sand and have had to put on my winter jacket. I have been to an amusement park built around a tall observation tower, walked in a snow-covered garden, visited a few museums and tried some lovely local delicacies on a pictoresque marketplace. Can you guess where I am?
>
> Wish you were here!
> Love, Gladys.

**Across**
1. Section of Noah's Ark Annie mistook for a place with coasters (11)
7. Ex-leader of Barbados is after cow hide (5)
10. Rowdy fans disturbed a solo balloon flight, cutting one of the lines (8,9)
11. Natural corruption of Robin by Batman's side (6)
12. Maybe Antony and Cleopatra found a place to swing (10)
14. Industry's leading character actor did fudge lines written down as a memory aid (5,4)
15. As overheard: "Darned! A carbonated beverage?" (4)
18. Not quite close to young lady (4,4)
19. Nick showers after others (8)
21. A container with lid slightly open (4)
23. After 5 April, thousands enter the third museum built in an old factory building (9)
26. It has a revolving restaurant and a nun dancing with aliens (10)
28. Fruit essential to Algonquin celebration (6)
30. Set straight a Midlands idiot – run cutting-edge technology? (10,7)
31. Fictional places of worship, built to honour the Seven Clans (5)
32. Prepared for timeless weather phenomenon (2,5,4)

**Down**
1. In cuisine, cooked turkey's topping is very strongly suitable (10)
2. Nirvana's leader expressed: "Composition of In Bloom? Hard like a diamond!" (10)
3. Clad in gold, Robert (extravagant man) shows summertime attraction (9)
4. Death metal group from the south of Réunion Island in France (4)
5. Expelled criminal held axe (7)
6. Possibly poisonous plant has gold colour (5)
7. Outrageously rich pianist Garland made shrill, trilling sounds (7)
8. End of war upset immature SEAL (4,2)
9. Live deer is butchered (6)
13. Language analyser misinterpreted spear head in Rome (6)
15. Child who writes novels is kidnapped by agent that's inactive (6)
16. Luna took off with Gladys, touring Red Square (10)
17. Cricket shot is going in the wrong direction in really heartless game (6,4)
20. Kind of roll seen in hearings or assemblies of a legal nature (9)
22. Has a craving for enviable neighbours? (7)
23. Criminal inhabiting immoral community (7)
24. Opens organisation which has 193 members and zero supporters initially (6)
25. Exhausted professor originally supporting American academic domain (4,2)
27. Second place in judo taken by son of two Olympians, getting circular pieces of valuable metal perhaps minted in Athens (5)
29. One member of US left-wing party is the same as the previous one (4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gladys is in

> Tampere, Finland

where she saw

> the SARKANNIEMI theme park, the ARBORETUM, the VAPRIIKKI museum, the NASINNEULA tower, and the marketplace at LAUKONTORI.

**Across**

> 1. SARKANNIEMI **substring** Section of Noah's Ark Annie mistook for *a place with coasters* (11)
> 7. COWER **ER (i.e., the Queen) after COW** Ex-leader of Barbados is after cow *hide* (5)
> 10. FOOTBALL HOOLIGANS **(A SOLO BALLOON FLIGHT - L)*** *Rowdy fans* disturbed a solo balloon flight, cutting one of the lines (8,9)
> 11. INBORN **ROBIN* + (-batma)N** *Natural* corruption of Robin by Batman's side (6)
> 12. PLAYGROUND **PLAY + GROUND** Maybe Antony and Cleopatra found *a place to swing* (10)
> 14. IDIOT CARD **(I(-ndustry) ACTOR DID)*** Industry's leading character actor did fudge *lines written down as a memory aid* (5,4)
> 15. SODA **homophone: SEWED A** As overheard: "Darned! A *carbonated beverage*?" (4)
> 18. NEAR MISS **ddef** *Not quite* close to young lady (4,4)
> 19. RESTRAIN **RAIN after REST** *Nick* showers after others (8)
> 21. AJAR **A JAR** A container *with lid slightly open* (4)
> 23. VAPRIIKKI **V + APR + KK in III** After 5 April, thousands enter the third *museum built in an old factory building* (9)
> 26. NASINNEULA **(A NUN ALIENS)*** *It has a revolving restaurant* and a nun dancing with aliens (10)
> 28. QUINCE **substring** *Fruit* essential to Algonquin celebration (6)
> 30. INDUSTRIAL DIAMOND **(A MIDLANDS IDIOT RUN)*** Set straight a Midlands idiot – run *cutting-edge technology?* (10,7)
> 31. SEPTS **ddef** Fictional places of worship, built to honour the Seven *Clans* (5)
> 32. ST ELMO'S FIRE **(FOR TIMELESS)*** Prepared for timeless weather phenomenon (2,5,4)

**Down**

> 1. SUFFICIENT **in (CUISINE* + T) is FF** In cuisine, cooked turkey's topping is very strongly *suitable* (10)
> 2. RHOMBOIDAL **(IN BLOOM HARD - N)*** Nirvana's leader expressed: "Composition of In Bloom? Hard *like a diamond*!" (10)
> 3. ARBORETUM **ROBERT* clad in AU, plus M** Clad in gold, Robert (extravagant man) shows *summertime attraction* (9)
> 4. NILE **(reunio)N + ILE** *Death metal group* from the south of Réunion Island in France (4)
> 5. EXHALED **(HELD AXE)*** *Expelled* criminal held axe (7)
> 6. IVORY **IVY contains OR** Possibly poisonous plant has gold *colour* (5)
> 7. CHIRRED **RICH* + RED** Outrageously rich pianist Garland *made shrill, trilling sounds* (7)
> 8. WRAP UP **WAR* + PUP** *End* of war upset immature SEAL (4,2)
> 9. RESIDE **(DEER IS)*** *Live* deer is butchered (6)
> 13. PARSER **SPEAR* + R(-ome)** *Language analyser* misinterpreted spear head in Rome (6)
> 15. SLEEPY **LEE kidnapped by SPY** Child who writes novels is kidnapped by agent that's *inactive* (6)
> 16. LAUKONTORI **(LUNA TOOK)* + I, touring R** Luna took off with Gladys, touring Red *Square* (10)
> 17. INSIDE EDGE **IS< in INDEED G(-am)E** *Cricket shot* is going in the wrong direction in really heartless game (6,4)
> 20. TRIBUNALS **BUN in TRIALS** Kind of roll seen in hearings or *assemblies of a legal nature* (9)
> 22. JONESES **("keeping up with ...")** *Has a craving for* enviable neighbours? (7)
> 23. VILLAGE **LAG inhabiting VILE** Criminal inhabiting immoral *community* (7)
> 24. UNZIPS **UN + ZIP + S(-upporters)** *Opens* organisation which has 193 members and zero supporters initially (6)
> 25. USED UP **P(-rofessor) supporting US + .EDU** *Exhausted* professor originally supporting American academic domain (4,2)
> 27. EUROS **(-j)U(-do) taken by EROS** Second place in judo taken by son of two Olympians, getting *circular pieces of valuable metal perhaps minted in Athens* (5)
> 29. IDEM **I + DEM(ocrat)** One member of US left-wing party is *the same as the previous one* (4)

Grid:

> [image]